# Which is the best criterion for comparing two conditional logit regressions with different variables?

Tags: regression, logit, clogit

Suppose we have two conditional logit models as below:

```
Model-1: clogit(win~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+strata(stratum))
Model-2: clogit(win~x6+x7+x8+strata(stratum))
```

I am getting lower AIC for model-2 and higher log-likelihood for model-1.

Which criterion should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AIC penalizes models that have more variables to protect against over-fitting (when the model explains the data you collected very well but doesn't generalize to outside data). Log-likelihood doesn't penalize this as it is a measure of how well your models fit the data used to make the models! In fact, if the variables in model 2 are a subset of the variables in model 1 (as they are in your case), then log-likelihood will always be bigger for model 1.

Since model 2 is a subset of model 1, if you've used the same data to fit each of the models, then I suggest performing a likelihood-ratio test comparing model 1 with model 2. This will answer the question, does model 1 fit significantly better than model 2?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I had used same data for both the model and both model are significant.

Comment: I'm suggesting comparing the two models to each other. Usually when we say "a model is significant" that's compared to using a model with just an intercept. You can do this in R by doing lrtest(model1, model2).

Comment: Thank you again, it works. But suppose one model is not significant how to compare.